# mergesort in c++:segmentation fault

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am getting segmentation fault while implementing mergesort.
I have checked for array out of bounds.I would love some help to find out where I have gone wrong.I have tried inputs for small arrays such as of size 10 where I have taken size of temp as static(>10).I have been pulling my hair out for hours.

UPDATE:  I only needed to change mid=(low+high)/2.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void merges(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high)
{
    int i=low,j=mid+1,k=0;
    int temp[high-low+1];
    while(i<=mid && j<=high)
    {
           if(arr[i]<arr[j])
            {
                temp[k++]=arr[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[k++]=arr[j];
                j++;               
            }
    }
    if(i>mid)
    {
        while(j<=high)
        {
            temp[k++]=arr[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(i<=mid)
        {
            temp[k++]=arr[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    j=0;
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=temp[j++];    
    }
}

void mergesort(int arr[],int low,int high)
{
    if(low<high)
    {
    int mid=low+high/2;
    mergesort(arr,low,mid);
    mergesort(arr,mid+1,high);
    merges(arr,low,mid,high);
    }   
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
    cin >> arr[arr_i];
    }
    int i,j,k;
    mergesort(arr,0,n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shen you get segmentation fault under debugger it should point where it happens. Didn't you run it under debugger or you are hiding this information from us?

Comment: Try changing mid to (low + high) / 2 instead of low + high / 2

Comment: Suggestion - make `mid` and `high` point to the element behind last, like standard C++ algos do. First of all that will make your code cleaner, second you can easily use standard algos (for example `std::copy` instead of loop). There is a reason why it is done this way in C++.

Comment: Note: variable-size array is illegal in c++ even if gcc compiles it

Comment: You are getting a stack overflow exception, meaning you're calling the `mergesort` function over and over again until the stack is exhausted.  Why didn't you recognize this when you were debugging?  At the very least, you could have printed out the values in your functions for debugging purposes, and see that you would have had an endless amount of amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i only needed to change mid=(low+high)/2. Thank you @Gerado Gálvez for your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

You're recursively calling mergesort. Although your general case seems legitimate, I cannot ascertain your base case (i.e. to exit the recursion).